# C++ - Sorting with an extra parameter

Tags: c++

I am working with an adjacency list and a map defined using the following type definitions :

```
typedef vector<list<Edge> > adjacencyList;
typedef map<int,WikiPage> idToWikiMap;
```

I would like to sort an adjacency list (`adjacencyList`) by name. The index of the `adjacencyList` is mapped to a pair in my map. For example,

```
adjacencyList lst;

lst[0] = NULL
lst[1] = list of edges related to City1
lst[2] = list of edges related to City2

idToWikiMap mymap;

mymap[1] -> Name of City1
mymap[2] -> Name of City2
```

So I want to sort the adjacency list using the name in the map related to the index of the adjacency list. I have come up with the following code. Since my compare function needs the map, I can't just create a normal function. So I used a `struct` and `Local`.

The compare works. I can `cout` the name of the lists currently being compared and the return value. For example, I get

```
Comparing Chicago and  New York
Smaller: 0
Comparing Montreal and  Chicago
Smaller: 1
Comparing Montreal and  New York
Smaller: 0
Comparing Toronto and  Chicago
Smaller: 1
Comparing Toronto and  Montreal
Smaller: 1
Comparing Toronto and  New York
Smaller: 1
Comparing Miami and  Chicago
Smaller: 1
Comparing Miami and  Montreal
Smaller: 0
```

However, the original does not get modified... Did I do something wrong?

```
  void printOrganized(adjacencyList& lst, idToWikiMap page_ofID) {
  // Define compare functions that accepts idToWikiMap parameter
  struct Local {
    Local(idToWikiMap mymap) { this->mymap = mymap; }

    bool operator() (const list<Edge>& l1, list<Edge>&l2)
    { return mymap.at(l1.front().origin).title < mymap.at(l2.front().origin).title; }

    idToWikiMap mymap;
  };

  /* Sort adjacenyList lst */
  sort (lst.begin()+1, lst.end(), Local(page_ofID));

  ...
  }
```

Comment: The values returned, but original is never overwritten. You pass by reference, but then make no assignment.

Comment: @OllieFord, I thought the comparison function was simply returning true/false for two objects and the algorithm `sort` would use that return value to sort. Does my function need to modify the passed objects?

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right, I misread. The actual issue is that `Local(page_ofID) == True`, in other words the first arg of `sort()` is always deemed less than the second. So when it's finished 'sorting' it's finished putting them in exactly the same order they were already in. It would probably be better procedural practice to write one function that performs the comparison, and is called from both the `printOrganised` and `sortCities` (or whatever name) functions.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting... I create a function `compare(const string t1, const string t2)`? That function will not have access to the map. I could pass the map along with the function, but then I don't see the point in creating calling an extra function when everything could be done inside the struct... thanks

Comment: You need to replace `Local(page_ofID)` with the comparison function. I suggested pulling this out merely to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked well for me, after I fixed a compilation error. Maybe your compiler isn't reporting this error, but it's causing your code not to work?

Anyway, the error is in the comparison function - you should get both parameters as const references, i.e.

```
bool operator() (const list<Edge>& l1, const list<Edge>& l2)
```

Also, I had to move `Local` to the global scope, because it wasn't working for me as long as it was defined inside the function. You can see the working result here: http://ideone.com/e.js/UPMeFm

Comment: Thanks for testing the code PaF! I took a look at your wrapper around `Local` and apparently, the problem came from the way I was fetching the page from `page_ofID`. I was using `page_ofID.at(iter-lst.begin())` instead of your `page_ofID.at(iter->front().origin);`.